# Adding Multiple Images or No Images to a Blog Post with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, replit

I am making a website for K-pop fans to post whatever about K-pop. I am currently following a tutorial to build the website, however I would like for the user to have the option to upload no photos or one or more photos. How can I achieve this?

(Here is the tutorial I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BI_VnnOLSKY)

I have tried searching up "Adding multiple photos or no photos using rails", however they only display "How to add photos to post" or etc.

I am using repl.it to make the website.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you want is to add multiple elements to a submission to achieve this, in Ruby on Rails you can use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), the standard functionality for including nested attributes in a submission:

```
#app/models/post.rb (or blog_post whatever your model name)
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :images # association with image model
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :images, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

In routes.rb file :-

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts
```

In controller file :-

```
#app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
class PostsController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @post = Post.new
     @post.images.build
   end

  .
  .
  .
end
```

The below code should give you a form for a @post, with embedded images inside.
To add "extra" fields, you'll be best looking at the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) or this Railscast: [Nested Forms part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Here I am using ["nested_form"](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) gem :-

```
#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= nested_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :x %>
  <%= f.text_field :y %>
  .
  .
  .

  <%= f.fields_for :images do |i| %>
     <% if i.object.new_record? %>
       <%= i.file_field :attachment %>
     <% else %>
       <%= image_tag i.object.attachment.url %>
     <% end %>
     <%= i.link_to_remove "Remove image" %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add image", :images%></p>


  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I hope the above code will help you to achieve your functionality :)